# Trajectory estimation

Tags: probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

The vertical coordinate (“height") of an object in free fall is described by an equation of the form
$x(t) = \theta _0 + \theta _1t + \theta _2 t^2,$

We assume that $\theta_0$ is a known constant. We also assume that $\theta_2$ is known. We view $\theta_1$ as the realized value of a continuous random variable $\Theta _1$.

In this case, finding the MAP estimate of $\Theta _1$ involves the minimization of
$$\theta _1^2+ \frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\sum _{i=1}^ n(y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _1 t_ i -\theta _2 t_ i^2)^2$$
with respect to $\theta_1$.

1)$$\hat{\theta }_1 = \frac{\sum ^ n_{i=1}t_ i(y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _2t^2_ i)}{\sigma ^2+\sum _{i=1}^ n t_ i^2}$$

2) Let$\sigma =1$, and consider the special case of only two observations($n=2$). Write down a formula for the mean squared error ${\bf E}[(\hat\Theta _1-\Theta _1)^2]$

my answer is $$1/(2(1+t_1^2+t_2^2))$$ I am not sure if it is right.

3) Consider the “experimental design" problem of choosing when to make measurements. Under the assumptions of part (1), and under the constraints $0\leq t_1,t_2\leq 10$, find the values of $t_1$ and $t_2$ that minimize the mean squared error associated with the MAP estimator.

I am really stuck here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

2) $${\bf E}[(\hat\Theta _1-\Theta _1)^2] = {\bf E}[(\hat\theta _1-\Theta _1)^2] = var(\Theta)$$
For a normal distribution, we recognize that the variance is determined by the coefficient that comes next to a term of the form $\theta _1^2$. So what we're looking for is the constant that sits next to the $\theta _1^2$ term. We collect all of them, it is $1/2*(1+t _1^2+t_2^2)$. So the final answer is
$$1/(1+t_1^2+t_2^2)$$

3)Because $0\leq t_1,t_2\leq 10$, in order to  minimize the mean squared error, I just guess $t_1=t_2=10$ intuitively.

Comment: Can you give more details how you got the terms for question 2?

Comment: Where did the $\sigma^2$ go?

Answer (score 0):

$\theta _1^2+ \frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\sum _{i=1}^ n(y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _1 t_ i -\theta _2 t_ i^2)^2$ is just for minimization use.

The original quadratic function of $\theta_1$ is $\frac{1}{2}\theta _1^2+ \frac{1}{2\sigma ^2}\sum _{i=1}^ n (y_ i-\theta _0-\theta _1 t_ i -\theta _2 t_ i^2)^2$.

Then we could use $var = \frac{1}{2\alpha}$ to calculate the final result.

Comment: I don't understand how $\sigma^2$ disappears from the final result.